# Repeat mapped XML values into Excel ListObject

Tags: excel, xml, vba, office365

### Background

I have several XML reports mapped to a two-column Excel ListObject (via a single XSD). The XML report files have the following layout:

```
<report>
    <general>
      <name/>
    </general>
    <data>
        <item/>
        ...
        <item/>
    </data>
</report>
```

The XPaths for each ListObject column are:

1. `/ns1:report/ns1:general/ns1:name`
2. `/ns1:report/ns1:data/ns1:item`

### Desired Output

A ListObject that has all individual “/report/data/item” records in the second column **and the single “/report/general/name” value repeated in the first ListObject column for *each* of those items** (so I may then query the ListObject to aggregate information in certain reports but not others).

### Current Output

Upon import of each XML file into an XMLMap (using `append` option), only the first `item` element appears in the second column and the corresponding `name` in the first column. The final ListObject contains that information for one record of each XML report file imported.

Correctness of whether one should assume reuse of XML elements aside, is there a way to obtain the desired output? Note that I have considered an XSLT to force the `item` elements to include the report `name`, but this seems like a poor use of memory/ disk space.

Comment: If you are restricted to XPath-1.0, it may be that you only get the first item `item` although the XPath expression does match both/several. I don't know how to circumvent this except for using an XSLT loop or XPath-2.0... Maybe someone else can provide a pure XPath-1.0 solution...

Comment: @zx485 thank you. Frustratingly, I believe MS has yet to adopt XML/XSLT/XPATH 2.0+ AFAIK. Further, the XPath used to map ListObject columns appears even more limited (for instance, I cannot find a way to use the `descendant-or-self` or `//` syntax in VBA — but haven’t thoroughly investigated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My test file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<report>
    <general>
      <name>MYNAME</name>
    </general>
      <data>
        <item>A</item>
        <item>B</item>
        <item>C</item>
        <item>D</item>
      </data>
</report>
```

looks like this

[image: Imported example]

if I opened it via OpenXML:

```
Private Sub ImportXMLperOpenXML()
    Dim tempWB As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set tempWB = Workbooks.OpenXML("....xml", , xlXmlLoadImportToList)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    tempWB.Sheets(1).Copy After:=ws
    tempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Interesting that the `Workbooks.OpenXML(...)` will repeat the single node. While this approach to open the XML as a new workbook demonstrates feasibility, this may not work as well as the XSLT solution in terms of performance to scale across multiple XML files. Nonetheless, optimistic that a ListObject XMLMap can also accommodate.

Comment: @Whee So I am curious, what you'll find out concerning performance. If it works, please consider to mark it as anwer as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Marking this as the answer (for those interested, performing the XSLT preprocessing offers an order-of-magnitude performance gain — though still don’t think the XSLT solution is particularly elegant)